# UITextField keyboard pop up after api response received

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

In my app am using UITextField in the login screen. To get the login details I connect the app to server through API. While calling the api I display an activity UIActivityIndicatorView. Before calling the api I do end editing. once the response is received from server again the keyboard is pop up when the activity indicator stops

Here is my Code

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
VW_overlay.hidden = NO;
[activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

[self performSelector:@selector(API_Login) withObject:activityIndicatorView afterDelay:0.01];
```

and the API_Login Method have the following code

```
-(void) API_Login
{
NSString *userEmail = _TXT_email.text;
NSString *userPWD = _TXT_password.text;
NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",userEmail,userPWD];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSString *urlGetuser =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@loginApi",SERVER_URL];
NSURL *urlProducts=[NSURL URLWithString:urlGetuser];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:urlProducts];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (aData)
 {
        NSMutableDictionary *json_DATA = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aData options:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        NSLog(@"The response %@",json_DATA);
        if ([[json_DATA valueForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[json_DATA valueForKey:@"driver_id"] forKey:@"driver_id"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[json_DATA valueForKey:@"status"] message:[json_DATA valueForKey:@"msg"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [alert show];

            [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
            VW_overlay.hidden = YES;

            [self performSelector:@selector(stop_activity) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[json_DATA valueForKey:@"status"] message:[json_DATA valueForKey:@"msg"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
        VW_overlay.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Error %@\nResponse %@",error,response);
    }
    }

-(void) stop_activity
{

    [self order_details_page];
}

-(void)order_details_page
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_order" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Where is endEditing method calling in your posted code ?

Comment: @SushilSharma I have edited my question please check

Comment: To hide the keyboard, you need to resign the keyboard before "-(void) API_Login". e.g. 
[_TXT_email resignFirstResponder];
[_TXT_password resignFirstResponder];

Comment: @SushilSharma I tried in that way also but not working

Comment: post code for stop_activity method.

Comment: @SushilSharma I have edited my question please check

Comment: and what does this segue do ? 
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_order" sender:self];

I have a question. Keyboard for which textfield pops-up?

Comment: In my current view controller login page I have text field and the detail view controller does not have any text field it displays only some details Keyboard pop up happens here(in destination view controller)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162885/discussion-between-sushil-sharma-and-aj-sanjay).